# Table MySql.proc doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, asp.net, terminal

I am new in asp.net and MySql, I have imported damp file in MYSql MAC and then got Error, Table MySql.proc doesn't exist.

After some research, i have upgrade mysql file in terminal, and then find this error. -> Could not create the upgrade info file '/usr/local/mysql/data/mysql_upgrade_info' in the MySQL Servers datadir, errno: 13

Now I am stuck there. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have resolved issue as my own. The problem was the latest version(8.0.12) of MySql, then i have uninstalled that version and downloaded older version(5.5.61), and now its working fine for me. Thanks